# Expand the linked list column in OrientDb

Tags: json, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Using Orient db 2.1.12(DocumentDB) version.Facing issues in expanding the linked list column .
Result of my orientdb query :

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#28:0",
            "@version": 7,
            "@class": "testSuite",
            "testSuiteName": "web",
            "testCaseLink": [
                "#20:0",
                "#20:1",
                "#20:2",
                "#20:3",
                "#20:4",
                "#20:5"
            ],
            "testingType": "Web",
            "@fieldTypes": "testCaseLink=z"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.061 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

testCaseLink is a property of linked list with values as rid of another class.The query used to obtain the above result **select * from testSuite**
Expected output :

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#28:0",
            "@version": 7,
            "@class": "testSuite",
            "testSuiteName": "web",
            "testCaseLink": [
                {
                    "@type": "d",
                    "@rid": "#20:0",
                    "@version": 5,
                    "@class": "testCase",
                    "name": "testForBAsu",
                    "uiJson": "#18:0",
                    "testcaseType": "webWithCsv",
                    "isEdited": false,
                    "isDeleted": false,
                    "childtestCaseLink": [
                        "#20:3",
                        "#20:4"
                    ],
                    "@fieldTypes": "uiJson=x,childtestCaseLink=z"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "d",
                    "@rid": "#20:1",
                    "@version": 6,
                    "@class": "testCase",
                    "name": "success",
                    "uiJson": "#18:1",
                    "testcaseType": "WebWithoutCsv",
                    "isEdited": true,
                    "isDeleted": false,
                    "eeJson": "#19:0",
                    "parentTestCaseLink": null,
                    "@fieldTypes": "uiJson=x,eeJson=x,parentTestCaseLink=x"
                },
                "#20:2",
                "#20:3",
                "#20:4",
                "#20:5"
            ],
            "testingType": "Web",
            "@fieldTypes": "testCaseLink=z"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.061 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

Need to Expand the rid present in the list.
Tired **select testSuiteName,testingType,Expand(testCaseLink) from testSuite where testSuiteName='web'**

But the query expands only the testCaseLink.Note:testCaseLink contains rid of different class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
select from testSuite FETCHPLAN *:1
```

Check [documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Fetching-Strategies.html) for more information.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

select from testSuite FETCHPLAN *:1